# Using PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF in django-tenant-schemas

Tags: django

I am trying to have django-tenant-schemas re-route users if they visit the base domain using the optional setting `PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF`. Whenever I visit the 
base url I get this response:

[image]

I'm hoping someone can tell me what the value of `PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF` should be based on my project structure or if anything else might be wrong. I want to use the urls from `public_website` when people try to access the base domain.

My project directory looks like this:

```
website
 ├──approvals
 ├──batches
 ├──customauth
 ├──email_portal
 ├──exports
 ├──file_downloads
 ├──password_reset
 ├──payroll
 ├──payroll_codes
 ├──reports
 ├──scheduling
 ├──shifts
 ├──static
 ├──templates
 ├──website
 |   ├──migrations
 |   ├──static
 |   ├──templates
 |   └──settings
 |       ├──__init__.py
 |       ├──base.py
 |       ├──prod.py
 |       └──dev.py
 ├──scheduling
 ├──public_website
 |   ├──__init__.py
 |   └──urls.py
 └──manage.py
```

And I want `PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF` to refer to the urls in `public_website`, which look like:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

import website.views as website_views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import HttpResponse

url_patterns = [
    url(r'^$', lambda request: HttpResponse('ok')),
    url(r'^admin/login/', website_views.Login.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))  # user authentication urls
]
```

Here are the relevant bits in my settings:

```
DJANGO_APPS = (
    'jet',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django_user_agents',
    'django_ses',
    # 'admin_reorder'
)

MY_APPS_WITH_MODELS = (
    'customauth',
    'payroll_codes',
    'scheduling',
    'payroll',
    'shifts',
    'email_portal',
    'tutor_training_tracker'
)

MY_APPS_WITHOUT_MODELS = (
    'exports',
    'reports',
    'file_downloads',
    'batches',
    'approvals'
)

SHARED_APPS = (
    'tenant_schemas',
    'website',
    'public_website'
)
TENANT_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + MY_APPS_WITH_MODELS
INSTALLED_APPS = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(SHARED_APPS + DJANGO_APPS + MY_APPS_WITHOUT_MODELS + MY_APPS_WITH_MODELS))
ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'
PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF = 'public_website.urls'
TENANT_MODEL = "website.Client"
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "tenant_schemas.storage.TenantFileSystemStorage"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Solution:

(Thanks to Thomas for writing the middleware for me)

Add custom middleware class:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import connection
from tenant_schemas.middleware import MIDDLEWARE_MIXIN
from tenant_schemas.utils import remove_www, get_tenant_model, get_public_schema_name


class CustomTenantMiddleware(MIDDLEWARE_MIXIN):
    def get_tenant(self, model, hostname, request):
        return model.objects.get(domain_url=hostname)

    def hostname_from_request(self, request):
        """ Extracts hostname from request. Used for custom requests filtering.
           By default removes the request's port and common prefixes.
       """
        return remove_www(request.get_host().split(':')[0]).lower()

    def process_request(self, request):
        # Connection needs first to be at the public schema, as this is where
        # the tenant metadata is stored.
        connection.set_schema_to_public()

        hostname = self.hostname_from_request(request)
        TenantModel = get_tenant_model()

        try:
            # get_tenant must be implemented by extending this class.
            tenant = self.get_tenant(TenantModel, hostname, request)
            assert isinstance(tenant, TenantModel)
            request.tenant = tenant
            connection.set_tenant(request.tenant)

        except (TenantModel.DoesNotExist, AssertionError):
            request.urlconf = settings.PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF
            request.public_tenant = True
            return

        if hasattr(settings, 'PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF') and request.tenant.schema_name == get_public_schema_name():
            request.urlconf = settings.PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF
```

and reference it in settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # 'tenant_schemas.middleware.TenantMiddleware',
    'website.middleware.CustomTenantMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django_user_agents.middleware.UserAgentMiddleware',
    'admin_reorder.middleware.ModelAdminReorder',
    'website.middleware.CustomTenantMiddleware',
    # 'djadmin.middleware.DJMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I maintain Django-Tenants which is a fork of django-tenant-schemas. The public url file gets called when the domain doesn't match a tenant. However depending on the middleware you have this can result in this not working. If this is the case write custom middleware for the tenant. You may also want edit you host file as it hard to test with out editing. What middleware are you using?

Comment: My hosts file is set to allow tenant1.localhost and tenant2.localhost, and both of those sites are working fine. It's just localhost that isn't directing me where I want. I have `'tenant_schemas.middleware.TenantMiddleware'` listed in my middleware.

Comment: have you changed PUBLIC_SCHEMA_NAME?

Comment: I have not changed it from the default value. I just now explicitly set it to 'public' with no change.

Comment: try a custom middleware. I have just knocked this together https://pastebin.com/4Ed2rPZ6

Comment: Wow, thanks, I have never used custom middleware so I'll figure out how to set it up and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I always use custom middleware for the schemas it gives you more power.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150545/discussion-between-thomas-turner-and-dragonbobz).

Comment: I'm having issues with this myself - did the custom middleware resolve it?

Comment: I have a youtube video on on how to set Django tenants up if that helps

Comment: @ThomasTurner  please i created a ticket on github / i'm using vuejs / rest_auth . what is the end point in this case to get the token

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed latest version of `django-tenants` and these settings are set in `settings.py`:

`SHOW_PUBLIC_IF_NO_TENANT_FOUND = True`    # I wonder why this setting is not meintioned in docs.

`PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF = 'project_name.urls_public'`